# How can I switch to non-default variant of keyboard layout on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, input-source

Currently I'm using Apple's Swiss German layout. I'd like to use the regular Swiss German layout but that is not available as a default input source.

The reason for this change is that characters such as `{,},[,] or ~` are either extremely awkward or impossible to type with one hand.

Is this possible on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom layout that does what you want with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Someone has already done something like this [here](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/mac-os-x-standard-de_ch-keymap/).